# Iterating over two lists, the first list is only going through the first value

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists, one of which consists of a list of first and last names (as one list item):

`FLIST = ["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"]` and so.

I then have another list which has

`JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"]]`, and so.

I am using the following output:

```
ultralist = []

for item in FList:
    for row in JG:
        if row[1] == item:
            ultralist.append(row)
```

Now I would expect to get a list of the rows in JG, where the value of row[1] is == to one of the list items in FList, but this is only happening for the first value of FList.

Can anyone tell me why and what I have to do to make this work?

Comment: What is the expected result of the code above?

Comment: "Now I would expect to get a list of the rows in JG, where the value of row[1] is == to one of the list items in FList"

Comment: So basically, if a value is in FList, and it is also in JG's row[1], then ultralist should contain that row of JG.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, I think Mikael's point is that your current input would exhibit exactly that behavior, because the only item that matches a value in JG is the first value of FList.

Comment: I've tested it works. "ultralist" contains every JG element which "name" part also exists in FList list

Comment: for me your code works as desired, i.e. ultralist contains multiple names if there are multiple matches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine:

```
>>> FList = ["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"]
>>> JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"], [7777, "Kevin Bacon"]]
>>> ultralist = []
>>> for item in FList:
    for row in JG:
        if row[1] == item:
            ultralist.append(row)


>>> ultralist
[[3928, 'Mary Smith'], [7777, 'Kevin Bacon']]
```

What was the problem?

---

While I'm at it, here would be a better way to do it. You don't need two for loops:

```
>>> FList = ["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"]
>>> JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"], [7777, "Kevin Bacon"]]
>>> ultralist = []
>>> for row in JG:
        if row[1] in FList:
                ultralist.append(row)


>>> ultralist
[[3928, 'Mary Smith'], [7777, 'Kevin Bacon']]
```

This method is more concise and makes the code easier to understand. First of all, you are attempting to do an operation on `JG`: find elements in it that match a certain criteria. So it's already clearer to first be iterating over `JG` and not `FList`. Then, instead of doing an explicit loop through `FList` to see if any of the names match `row[1]`, you can use the short-cut `row[1] in FList`. This does a for-loop internally, anyway, but it's really clear what the intent of the code is.

What would be faster would be to use a `set` for `FList`:

```
>>> FList = set(["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"])
>>> JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"], [7777, "Kevin Bacon"]]
>>> ultralist = []
>>> for row in JG:
        if row[1] in FList:
                ultralist.append(row)


>>> ultralist
[[3928, 'Mary Smith'], [7777, 'Kevin Bacon']]
```

Notice that the loop code doesn't change. What's different is that the `in` operation for sets is much, much faster than for lists. You don't have to iterate through every element, but rather, you do some fancy hash lookups.

And even better would be to just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> FList = set(["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"])
>>> JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"], [7777, "Kevin Bacon"]]
>>> ultralist = [row for row in JG if row[1] in FList]
>>> ultralist
[[3928, 'Mary Smith'], [7777, 'Kevin Bacon']]
```

This code is simply more concise and thus even easier to understand.

Comment: What makes these methods better? Faster?

Comment: Yea, let me update my question to make it more explicit. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only prints the first item in the list is because there is no "Jacob Francis" in FLIST.

As a side note, make sure the capitalization of FLIST stays constant.

Here's a possible implementation using a single list comprehension.

```
FLIST = ["Mary Smith", "Kevin Bacon"]
JG = [[3928, "Mary Smith"], [2920, "Jacob Francis"]]

ultralist = [x for x in JG if x[1] in FLIST]
```